# Launcher intent is in manifest, but no launcher activity found

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I'm pretty new to android development. I created a project using android studio, and chose my first activity to be a login activity. After changing some basic stuff in the layout/trying to add some functionality in java, thought I'd do a test run. While trying to build apk and install the app, it installs fine on my phone but AIDE (A development android app) says that no launcher activity is found. Here's my manifest file:

```
    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />    
    <uses-permission   android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />    

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"    
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"    
        android:label="@string/app_name"    
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >    
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"    
            android:label="@string/app_name"    
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >    
            <intent-filter>    
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
                <category android:name="android.intent.categor.LAUNCHER" />    
            </intent-filter>    
        </activity>    
    </application>    

</manifest>
```

So what am I missing? I've searched a lot but I ant find an answer that applies to my scenario. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: try using the full name of Activity class - `com.rrdevs.peerboard.LoginActivity`

Comment: change ""android.intent.categor.LAUNCHER"  to ""android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" ......you miss "y"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! It seems to work now that I corrected the spelling of category.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<category android:name="android.intent.categor.LAUNCHER" />
```

It Should be

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much, that worked! Can't believe I didn't notice it before!

Comment: You are welcome. We should be extra careful when working with the AndroidManifest.xml file. A simple typo can ruin things. I see that you are new in Stackoverflow. So let me remind you that if an answer helps to solve your problem, you should accept the answer. Here is how:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow